# use docker containers to simulate one network on different machine

Tags: docker

I have two machine both contains 4GB RAM.
I wish to simulate 6 docker containers with 1GB RAM and all of them on same network.

Is it possible? How to configure it?

```
PC1:192.168.2.10
  d1: 192.168.1.1
  d2: 192.168.1.2
  d3: 192.168.1.3
PC2:192.168.2.11
  d4: 192.168.1.4
  d5: 192.168.1.5
  d6: 192.168.1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a use case for [docker swarm](https://github.com/docker/swarm), which ([from its documentation](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/)) turns a pool of Docker hosts into a single, virtual host.

That would allow you to consider both machines as nodes, and run on it 6 containers, allocating to each one 1GB.